# Find all 3^4 permutation using lists

Tags: python

Let's say I have 4 distinguishable balls, and I want to distribute them into 3 cells (that's 3^4 different ways of doing that) - how would you suggest me to demonstrate all those 81 different distributions using Python?

I want my program to return a list that contains 81 lists, each contain 3 lists representing the 3 cells, where in each sub-list there are numbers 1-4.

hope you understood what i meant.. it's a bit complicated interpretation.

I'll try to give an example of how my list should look like:

```
[
  [ [1,2] , [3,4] , []  ]  # cell #1 contains the balls 1,2 and cell #2 contains the balls 3,4 and cell #3 is empty
  [ [1,2] , [3] , [4]  ]  # cell #1 contains the balls 1,2 and cell #2 contains ball 3 and cell #3 contains ball 4
  [ [1,2] , [] , [3,4]  ]  # cell #1 contains the balls 1,2, cell #2 is empty and cell #3 contains the balls 3,4
...
]
```

Comment: So do you have any code that doesn't do what you're asking for?

Comment: And in your example, `[ [1,2] , [3,4] , [] ]` and `[ [1,2] , [] , [3,4] ]` are not equivilent?

Comment: @ChrisOram
no, they are not. The order of the sub-lists is important. each sub-list indicates a cell. the first sub-list is cell #1, and etc..
The order of the number INSIDE each sub-list is not important. hence, ```[ [1,2] , [3,4] , [] ]``` is the same like ```[ [2,1] , [4,3] , [] ]```.

The sub-lists are like sets, while the list itself (their "father") is an array.
Hope that's clafity some things:)

Comment: @Shinratensei

I tried something but it was so incorrect. in fact, i don't have any idea how to do this, that's why i'd be really happy if you could help me

Comment: Posting what you've tried, no matter how incorrect it is, is always better than posting no code whatsoever, because at the very least you show you've tried to solve your problem which is a minimum requirement to ask a good question on SO, and people will be more eager to help you. In this case lots of people have already answered but for the future and for other people, posting the code really helps everyone involved.

Comment: @Shinratensei
Alright, i'll take this to my attention. thanks for telling me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is simple and bruteforce, but working, example:

```
import itertools
import pprint

balls = set('1234')
splits = []
for i in range(0,len(balls)+1): # python ranges are upper-bound exclusive
    bucket_1_possibilities = (set(x) for x in itertools.combinations(balls,i))
    for bucket1 in bucket_1_possibilities:
        for j in range(0,len(balls)-i+1): # in the second cell there may be up to len(balls)-i balls 
            bucket_2_possibilities = list(set(x) for x in itertools.combinations(balls-bucket1,j))
            for bucket_2 in bucket_2_possibilities:
                splits.append([list(bucket1), list(bucket_2),list(balls-bucket1-bucket_2)])
pprint.pprint(splits)
print(len(splits))
```

Itertools.combinations (https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) allow you to get possible contents of first cell. From remaining balls you get possible contents of second cells, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
import collections
from itertools import chain, combinations, permutations

test = [1, 2, 3, 4]

result = filter(lambda el:
                len([item for item, count in collections.Counter([item for sublist in el for item in sublist]).items()
                     if count > 1]) == 0
                and len([item for sublist in el for item in sublist]) == len(test),
                list(permutations(set(chain.from_iterable(combinations(test, r) for r in range(len(test) + 1))), 3)))

print(result)
```

**Explanation**: First of all, you search [powerset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of `test`, and when searching all possible combinations of elements of the powerset by 3.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be right... The first three elements are `((2, 3), (1, 4), (4,))`, `((1, 3), (), (3,))` and `((2, 3), (1, 3, 4), (1, 2, 4))`... Maybe I didn't understand the question but that seems wrong...

Comment: Thanks @Tomerikoo, my bad, fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Instead of lists in list, a simpler interpretation is to think of a list of the balls position. See code below. The code is written in a lengthy way so that the logic is easy to follow.

```
combinations = []
for ball1 in range(3): # for all possible buckets we can put ball #1
    for ball2 in range(3): # for all possible buckets we can put ball #2
        for ball3 in range(3): # for all possible buckets we can put ball #3
            for ball4 in range(3): # for all possible buckets we can put ball #4
                ball_positions = [ball1, ball2, ball3, ball4]
                buckets = [[], [], []]
                for ball in range(4): # For each ball
                    bucket = ball_positions[ball] # This is the ball's position
                    buckets[bucket].append(ball) # So let's put the ball in this bucket
                combinations.append(buckets)                    

for i in range(len(combinations)): 
    print(i, combinations[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use product from itertools to iterate over all combinations of several iterators. I think you are looking for something like this:

```
from itertools import product
main_list = []
for i,j,k,l in product(range(3),range(3),range(3),range(3)):
  sub_list = [[] for _ in range(3)]
  sub_list[i].append(1)
  sub_list[j].append(2)
  sub_list[k].append(3)
  sub_list[l].append(4)
  main_list.append(sub_list)
print(main_list)
```

or even more pythonic - replace `product(range(3),range(3),range(3),range(3))`
with `product(*[range(3) for _ in range(4)])`
and for better printing instead of `print(main_list)` use

```
for combination in main_list:
  print(*combination)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to look at this is: we "cut-off" the list of balls in two places. Go over all the possible cutoff points, and construct the "buckets" according to them. For example, to make the code clearer:

For a list of balls, `balls = [1, 2, 3, 4]`, one cut-off is at indexes `cutoff = [1, 2]` which means that the buckets are:

- from the start until index 1: `[1]`
- from index 1 until index 2: `[2]`
- from index 2 until the end: `[3, 4]`

This is done using [`combinations_with_replacement`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement) as we only want incremental indexes:

```py
import itertools

balls = [1, 2, 3, 4]
buckets = 3

cutoffs = itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(len(balls)+1), buckets-1)
for cutoff in cutoffs:
    cutoff = (None,) + cutoff + (None,)
    permutation = [balls[i:j] for i, j in zip(cutoff, cutoff[1:])]
    print(cutoff[1:-1], ':', permutation)
```

The (truncated) output of this will be:

```
(0, 0) : [[], [], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
(0, 1) : [[], [1], [2, 3, 4]]
(0, 2) : [[], [1, 2], [3, 4]]
...
(1, 3) : [[1], [2, 3], [4]]
(1, 4) : [[1], [2, 3, 4], []]
(2, 2) : [[1, 2], [], [3, 4]]
...
(4, 4) : [[1, 2, 3, 4], [], []]
```